# has_many relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relationship in which I'm trying to reference two different foreign keys. Excuse the lame example here, but I'd like to do something like the following:

```
class Account
  has_many :orders, 
    -> { where('orders.account_id IS NULL OR orders.account_id = ?', self.id ) },
    primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

However the dynamic value in the where clause is not correct, throwing a 'NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for ActiveRecord_Relation'.

Any ideas on how to reference the parent record within the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a record to call `.id` on. I guess that this is what you are looking for:

```
class Account
  has_many :orders, 
    -> { where('orders.account_id IS NULL OR orders.account_id = accounts.id') },
    primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just came across the answer. By providing a property to the lambda, rails will provide the record.

```
class Account
  has_many :orders, 
    ->(record) { where('orders.account_id IS NULL OR orders.account_id = ?', record.id ) },
    primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it doesn't work with eager loading. With this, a record is not provided to the proc, and an error is thrown.